# Magento 1.9.1.1 does not calculate TAX

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento is not calculating TAX even if article prices are entered including TAX and all TAX classes etc. are configured correct.
I'm using an German Shop (Locale Pack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some wrong translation in the german locale Pack which let's you think that you have to choose the country on which the tax should be calculated under:

`SYSTEM -> CONFIGURATION -> SALES -> TAX -> DEFAULT TAX DESTINATION CALCULATION`

but the Setting has to be done under:

```
SYSTEM -> CONFIGURATION -> SALES -> SHIPPING SETTINGS -> ORIGIN
```

The translation in German only says "Default Tax Calculation", the Destination is lost.